# ¿Como asigno valores de un arreglo a otro?

Tags: array, funciones, vba, loops

Quiero hacer una función que me devuelva en específico una posición de un arreglo de una longitud más pequeña con respecto a otro en VBA - Excel, todos mis valores son múltiplos de 28 y tenía esta idea en mente:

```
Public Function arreglo_corto(rango As Range, termino As Integer) As Double

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim curva As Double
ReDim curva(390)


For i = 1 To 390
  j = i * 28
  curva(i) = rango(j)
Next i


arreglo_corto = curva(termino)


End Function
```

Pero nada más me regresa el error '#¡REF!', ¿podrían ayudarme a una solución más clara o a decirme en qué me estoy equivocando?

Gracias :)

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. En tu código. ¿Qué es IRSVm? ¿Qué es irs29? Qué es objTerm? Entiendo que quieres crear una matriz de nombre `curva` y que en cada posición de la matriz, quieres meter `i*28` pero el final de tu función me confunde. Y tienes variables que no aparecen definidas. ¿Són públicas?. Y tu función pide 2 parámetros, que son `rango` y `termino`. Pero luego no los usas. ¿Por qué?

Comment: rango llega a tener 28*390 elementos?

Comment: Hola! No había corregido el,cambio de mis variables, espero que con la actualización sea más clara mi,duda.

Comment: Rango tiene 28*390 elementos, curva sólo tiene 390.

Comment: ¿Qué `rango`tienes seleccionado cuando ejecutas esta función? ¿Cuál es el valor de `termino`? Es que además, no termino de entender qué es lo que quieres obtener con esta UDF :O

Comment: Chicos, al parecer solo era una bronca de debugging :) Gracias por su ayuda.